# Sugar Snap Pea pods have white fuzz inside

Tags: vegetables, peas

I have some sugar snap peas that appear to have a healthy pod exterior and the actual peas seem to be healthy, but there's a bit of white fuzz inside the pod itself.

A bit looking around points to maybe some type of fungus or mold? Or is this normal for sugar snap peas? There's no signs of powdery mildew on the pods that I can see and the fuzz seems to be a bit worse in the pea pods closer to being ready for harvest rather than still being a bit too young.

[image: sugar snap pea pod planted]

Thanks for your time!